# What’s is the ideal approach for versioning packages in a monorepo?

Tags: javascript, monorepo

I have a ReactJS project in a monorepo setup like so—

```
monorepo root
├── external dashboard
├── internal dashboard
└── shared components
```

Now, what are some best practices to maintain versioning here?

Should the entire monorepo be versioned at the root, or have individual versions for each of these folders inside? They are all very tightly coupled, and ideally, they would progress together as a whole.

What are some pros and cons of either approach?

Comment: "*would progress together as a whole*" - does that mean you'd release them together?

Comment: Yup, under ideal conditions. But say, some hotfixes could go out independently, in either of the dashboards.

Comment: Sounds more like a single project to me. It doesn't sound like there's a good reason to version the folders separately.